# How to convert Object contains IList<class> which further contains 6 properties - 4 string, 1 IList<anotherclass>, 1 IList<string> to DataTable?

Tags: c#, list, object, datatable

I am trying to convert my Object which have only 1 item (IList of class), this class contains 6 properties - 4 string, 1 IList of anotherClass and 1 IList of string.
I am using below generic method to convert :-

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IList<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        //Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            //Defining type of data column gives proper data table 
            var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);
            //Setting column names as Property names
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
        }

        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                //inserting property values to datatable rows
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
        return dataTable;
    }
```

At this point - **dataTable.Rows.Add(values);** I have the list values for 4 and 5 properties but when I add those to row, it shows text(type of property) in the row. While I need each item of 4 and 5 properties to come in next Row.
For Example :-

```
values[0] - "FirstString",
values[1] - "SecondString",
values[2] - "ThirdString",
values[3] - "FourthString",
values[4] - Count 2 - 100, 200 (IList<AnotherClass>()),
values [5] - Count 2 - "10W", "20W" (IList<string>)
```

I want below type of output :-

```
1String     | 2String      | 3String     | 4String      | Per | W  |
:-----------|:------------:|:-----------:|:------------:|:---:|---:|
FirstString | SecondString | ThirdString | FourthString | 100 | 10W|
FirstString | SecondString | ThirdString | FourthString | 200 | 20W|
```

While the output I am currently getting is :-

```
1String     | 2String      | 3String     | 4String      | Per            | W                 |
:-----------|:------------:|:-----------:|:------------:|:--------------:|--------------:|
FirstString | SecondString | ThirdString | FourthString | typeofproperty | typeofproperty|
```

I just want my object's list to convert to DataTable.

Below is the debugging result as per the solution given below:-
[image]

@Dennis, Still getting type of property as value for list type property.
[image]

Comment: You need to flatten your objects first to get your code working. It won't be easy to do it in generic manner, because T can be anything, so as flatten logic. It would be much easier, if `items` will be conversion-ready DTO with scalar properties only (I mean no collections or another nested objects).

Comment: The calling of this method is toDataTable<anotherClass>(IList<anotherClass>).
How I can flatten the object?

Comment: The caller has to do it. Otherwise it won't be trivial. Another option is to bring limitations for `T` structure (e.g. 2 lists only, list lengths are the same), but in this case general-purpose converter makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for `T` which contains only scalar properties (that is, primitive types, strings, dates, etc).
When it deals with collection or nested object, it tries to store that object or collection in data table's row as is, so the result is not as you expected.

To get the output you want, you need to flatten list items first.
Since `T` could be anything, flatten logic cannot be implemented in generic manner. But the caller can do this for you, since he knows everything about object structure.

Having these types:

```
class Foo
{
    public string A { get; set; }

    public string B { get; set; }

    public string C { get; set; }

    public string D { get; set; }

    public IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public IList<string> Strings { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}
```

you can write this code:

```
var items = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo
    {
        A = "FirstString",
        B = "SecondString",
        C = "ThirdString",
        D = "FourthString",
        Bars = new List<Bar>
        {
            new Bar { A = 100 },
            new Bar { A = 200 }
        },
        Strings = new List<string>
        {
            "10W",
            "20W"
        }
    }
};

var dataTable = items
    .SelectMany(item => item.Bars.Zip(item.Strings, (bar, stringValue) => new
    {
        BarA = bar.A,
        StringValue = stringValue
    }),
    (item, _) => new
    {
        item.A,
        item.B,
        item.C,
        item.D,
        _.BarA,
        _.StringValue
    })
    .ToDataTable();
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, flatten logic inside `SelectMany` depends on what `T` is. If there will be, say, 3 nested lists and `Bar` will contain `public Boo { get; set; }` property, that logic will change to reflect new object structure.

P.S. I've modified `ToDataTable` definition a little to make it extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
static class ConversionExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, What is item.Strings and stringValue in the example?

item.Bars.Zip(item.Strings, (bar, stringValue) => new
    {
        BarA = bar.A,
        StringValue = stringValue
    })

Comment: `item.Strings ` is `IList<string>` property in `Foo` class. `stringValue`  is an item of `item.Strings `. I guess, you''re asking mostly about `Zip` method - it just makes from two sequences of different types the third one. Literally, makes the sequence of pairs (100, "10W"), (200, "20W").

Comment: Yeah got that working, but after defining items it's not letting me call ToDataTable() method. Asking me to define type. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @EktaC, well, I don't know how your modified code looks like. :) If you can post or share it, please do this.

Comment: Please look at the below screenshot provided by me.

Comment: Define `ToDataTable` as extension method. See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: Updated the answer to show how to define extension method, see `ConversionExtensions` class.

Comment: Can you please share your ToDataTable() method you have used for the shown output, please? @Dennis

Comment: @EktaC, actually, it's your code from the original post. :) I've just copied/pasted it without any changes. The source: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1J5O1H

Comment: Please check the screenshot value is not coming from the list type properties. But number of rows increased as per the number of items.

Comment: @EktaC, you're passing `item.ToString()` as a second sequence into `Zip` method. Hence, you're "zipping" every `Per_100` item with every character in `SmallType`'s type name. I doubt this is what you want.